# 64 bit windows library target platform generated .o and .a file in RAD studio C++

Tags: c++, c++builder

Creating 64 bit windows library for Static linking.
Target Framework is Firemonkey.

If 32 bit windows library is building in RAD studio C++, then output files are .obj and .lib.
 And if built with 64 bit windows target platform, output files are .o and .a (expecting .lib file). Added this .a file for static linking in 64 bit windows application. Gives linking errror " [ilink64 error] fatal: unable to open file .a ".
How to generate .obj and .lib file for 64 bit windows platform?

Comment: You don't. The `.o` and `.a` files are the right ones. Your error seems to hint at the fact that the .a file can't be opened, perhaps because it can't be found. Set the appropriate directories for your Win64 setup separately.

Comment: Use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to watch the exact path the linker uses to access the `.a` file and see whether it fails because the path is wrong or because the file is in use.

Comment: @Remy: perhaps the verbose output from the build process could be a hint too, i.e. where the linker expects what.